# JavaScript is not storing HTML input value

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a rock paper scissors game with HTML, CSS, and JS. I give the user two inputs where they can enter their name and the CPU's name. Then when they click play, I can store those values. As of now, I log them in console to see if it works. However, the input value is always empty despite me entering something. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```js
let playerName = document.getElementById("player-name").value;
let cpuName = document.getElementById("cpu-name").value;
if (playerName === "") {
    playerName = "You";
}
if (cpuName === "") {
    cpuName = "CPU";
}

let play = document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(playerName, cpuName);
});
```

```html
    <input id="player-name" class="names" type="text" placeholder='Enter Your Name'>
    <input id="cpu-name" class="names" type="text" placeholder='Enter CPU Name'>
    <button id="play">Play</button>
```

Comment: With the exception of the console.log() line, that JS code runs when the page loads, and  the inputs are still empty. An assignment like `let playerName = document.getElementById("player-name").value;` does not permanently bind the variable to the .value; it runs once and has no effect in the future.

Comment: Is there a way I could permanently bind the variable to the .value?

Comment: Only if you use a framework like Angular or React, which are basically built around that concept.

Comment: @JoshuaLiu You could define getters on an object, but you should just take the values in the click handler.

Comment: You should move getting the value into the event handler. No need for Angular or React

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to imply you should switch to React. Just move all your code inside the function, so it all runs after Play is clicked.

Comment: This is a common problem that has been asked about previously, including in [Why can't I get the input from the input box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396061/why-cant-i-get-the-input-from-the-input-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get those value while onclick event:

```js
let play = document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", () => {
   let playerName = document.getElementById("player-name").value;
   let cpuName = document.getElementById("cpu-name").value; 
   if (playerName === "") {
     playerName = "You";
   }
   if (cpuName === "") {
     cpuName = "CPU";
   }  
   console.log(playerName, cpuName);
});
```

```html
    <input id="player-name" class="names" type="text" placeholder='Enter Your Name'>
    <input id="cpu-name" class="names" type="text" placeholder='Enter CPU Name'>
    <button id="play">Play</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```js
let playerName;
let cpuName;

let play = document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", () => {
playerName = document.getElementById("player-name").value;
cpuName = document.getElementById("cpu-name").value; 
if (playerName == null) {
 playerName = "You";
}
if (cpuName == null) {
 cpuName = "CPU";
}  
console.log(playerName, cpuName);
});
```

```html
    <input value="" id="player-name" class="names" type="text" placeholder='Enter Your Name'>
    <input value="" id="cpu-name" class="names" type="text" placeholder='Enter CPU Name'>
    <button id="play">Play</button>
```