# `document.getElementById("is-student").checked` is not take the correct value from the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Hi This is a HTML code for a check box. I need to take the value of the checkbox(true/false).

```
<input id="is-student" type="checkbox" value="Student Related"/>
<input id="open-new" type="button" value="Open New" onclick="openNew();"/>
```

This is the java script code for take the input value from the checkbox.

```
var testJson = JSON.stringify({
  reference: [{
     studentRelated: document.getElementById("is-student").checked
  }]
});

function openNew()
{
    window.openNew(testJson);
}
```

My problem is `document.getElementById("is-student").checked` always return false. If we click the checkbox, this part returns false, and if we not click the checkbox, then also return false.

I need to fix that and when we click the checkbox, then `document.getElementById("is-student").checked` part should return true and if we did not click, then should be return `false`. How can I do that?

Comment: can you show us your full event listener for your checkbox?

Comment: yes I have added the full event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global variable not changing on event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120122/global-variable-not-changing-on-event)

Comment: See also [Why can't I get the input from the input box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55396061/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `testJson` inside the `openNew` method so that the value is updated. Right now the JSON is set on load and the values are not updated on checkbox select. Try this code

```
function openNew()
{

  var testJson = JSON.stringify({
    reference: [{
       studentRelated: document.getElementById("is-student").checked
    }]
  });
    window.open(testJson);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `testJson` variable appears to be set before your function is called, so unless your checkbox is pre-checked, `studentRelated` will always be false.
If you want it to reflect the checkbox's status when the button is clicked, you need to evaluate whether it's checked when the function is called, not before.