# Having trouble getting some JS Math to work

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small project for tuning a car in a game. Allowing users to input the own numbers and have them calculated and then displayed on the screen. The user would input a max number(65) a min number(1) and a percentage(55). And here is the equation I'm trying to complete: (65-1) *.55 +1.

I've linked all of the inputs in the .js file, and I can update the text on the screen as well, but can't get the equation to work properly. The problem starts when I try to multiple by the percentage(.55). And I haven't even added the + 1 yet either. I thought maybe I was having a problem converting from a string to a number as I was receiving 'NaN' in the console. But I'm really not sure when the problem is. Any help or suggestions on how to do this better would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more information

```js
// ========== Main Variables ==========
const weight = document.querySelector('#fWeightUserInput').value;
const frontWeight = parseInt(weight);
const antiRollMin = document.querySelector('#antiRollMin');
const antiRollMax = document.querySelector('#antiRollMax');

const mainForm = document.querySelector('#mainForm');

// ===== Final Tune Text =====
const antiRollFrontTxt = document.querySelector('#calcAntiRollFrontNum');
const antiRollRearTxt = document.querySelector('#calcAntiRollRearNum');
// ========== Tune Math Calculations ===========

mainForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const antiRollFront =
    (antiRollMax.value - antiRollMin.value) * (frontWeight / 100);
  console.log(frontWeight);
  antiRollFrontTxt.innerText = antiRollFront;
});
```

Comment: You're setting `frontWeight` when the page is first loaded, not after the user inputs the value.

Comment: Please put your HTML in your snippet so it works properly.

Comment: You need to get the values of all the inputs in the event listener.

Comment: convert the text inputs (string types) to int or float depending on what you need. INPUT type is a string so you must turn them into number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I get the input from the input box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396061/why-cant-i-get-the-input-from-the-input-box)

Comment: what @Heretic said. Move your variables inside of your eventListener function. Then they will update every time when someone clicks. And btw: you do not need to parseInt(). Javascript does that for you ("10" / "2" === 5)

Comment: Thank you all for your help!