# The value in my number input won't change with user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am trying to multiply the value that the user will choose from the input box by an already set value of 0.1 but the value that is fetched from the input is either 0 or stays as the default value already set. The value (ex: 8) that is chosen by the user won't be taken as the new updated value.

This is the input:

```html
<div>Number:<input type="number" id="NumberToMultiply" min="1" max="100" value="1"></input></div>
```

This is the script that is fetching the value inputted by the user:

```
var amount = document.getElementById("NumberToMultiply").value;
```

This is the line that is making the equation:

```
const Result = (amount)*(0.1)
```

The thing is that even if I chose the number "43" with the input, the value fetched from the input is still 1.

Comment: What you are not showing in your question is _when_, _how_, that line `var amount = ...etc...` is getting called. Do you have a button? Is there some event listener attached to the input field "NumberToMultiply"?

Comment: The value is always 1 because you are likely only fetching the value once, at page load, not when the value is changed or a button is pressed. That's the reason for @StephenP's leading question.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Chances are, you are only accessing the input element's value at runtime and not listening to the `input` event on the element itself.

Comment: @Hold Your edit changed the code such that the field no longer had a default value of 1, but rather 43, which caused the last sentence to no longer make any sense. Please be more careful when editing. I don't know that a snippet makes much sense here, until the OP responds to Stephen P's request for clarification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I get the input from the input box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396061/why-cant-i-get-the-input-from-the-input-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var amount = document.getElementById("NumberToMultiply").value;
const Result = amount * 0.1;
console.log(Result);
document.getElementById("NumberToMultiply").oninput = function () {
    console.log(document.getElementById("NumberToMultiply").value * 0.1);
}

<div>Number:<input type="number" id="NumberToMultiply" min="1" max="100" value="1"></input></div>
```

That should do the trick, the problem was you didn't have any event on user trigger, just on load